# Ace editor is not editing the text

Tags: ace-editor

I am not able to edit the text in ace editor.
I am using the following code to do the same

```
 var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setValue(ed.getContent(), -1) 
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html").setReadOnly(false);
```

the link to code is [here](https://codepen.io/mantuonweb/pen/LMGvQG).
can some one help me out to resolve this issue?

Comment: I find 2 editors in your code snippet. You are trying to make 2 editors editable?

Comment: editor in the codepen doesn't work because you have display:none rule for all textareas in www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css